# What is difference of pam.d config ubuntu and redhat?

Tags: linux, pam

While handling pam.d setting on Ubuntu and RedHat,

I saw something like this on Ubuntu

```
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
auth    [default=ignore]        pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1]     pam_succeed_if.so user = sos
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

And like below from RedHat(CentOS)

```
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

And I seems like (I'm not sure) that 
in RedHat, syntax like `[success=3]` doesn't work.

What is the difference between two and Where is document? 
Any guide would be appreciated.

Comment: The version of pam.

Comment: (I am guessing now) 
PAM is just one of kind (made by morgan@kernel.org, kukuk@thkukuk.de, just tiny version difference). So Ubuntu and RedHat both supports '[succes=3]' syntax.

my bad.